# asp.net mvc tutorial - where is it storing my login data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i downloaded asp.net mvc and i am playing around with the main tutorial.

In the upper right, when i click log in or register new user, i am trying to understand where this data is being stored.  I dont see any SQL database or any other data store.

i see something that says this below:

```
                // Attempt to register the user
            MembershipCreateStatus createStatus = MembershipService.CreateUser(userName, password, email);
```

but again, i can't find the actual data store.

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will copy `aspnetdb.mdf` file to `App_Data` directory when you use membership services for the first time.

You can manually create a SQL Server database by [`aspnet_regsql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74.aspx) and set the `ApplicationServices` connection string in `web.config`.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to take a look at the SQL Server Publishing Wizard found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=56E5B1C5-BF17-42E0-A410-371A838E570A&displaylang=en).

It essentially allows you to copy the database structure and/or data to a .sql file that you can then import into your primary SQL database.

I don't particularly like the aspnetdb approach but that's my personal opinion.